# Ignore files for zsh's completion for SVN

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete, subversion

I managed to configure `zsh` such that it does not suggest LaTeX temporary files when I use autocompletion for emacs by adding this line to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:emacs:*:*files' ignored-patterns '*?.aux' '*?.bbl' \
'*?.blg' '*?.out' '*?.log' '*?.toc' '*?.snm' '*?.nav' '*?.pdf' '*?.bak' '*\~'
```

Now zsh ignores all LaTeX temporary files when I request completions for `emacs`.

How can I achieve the same for `svn add`?

So far I have only found out that the completion for `svn` is rather complicated and was even broken for some time. Just exchanging `emacs` in the above example does not work because I need to affect the completion for the `add` parameter of `svn`.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer too. This page could help: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html. I'm currently reading it to see what could be hacked around zstyle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line will give you what you want:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:svn-add:*:*files' ignored-patterns '*?.aux' '*?.bbl' \
'*?.blg' '*?.out' '*?.log' '*?.toc' '*?.snm' '*?.nav' '*?.pdf' '*?.bak' '*\~'
```

From http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html:

> The command or a special -context-, just at it appears following the #compdef tag or the compdef function. Completion functions for commands that have sub-commands usually modify this field to contain the name of the command followed by a minus sign and the sub-command. For example, the completion function for the cvs command sets this field to cvs-add when completing arguments to the add subcommand.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks a lot. I now also added cvs by exchanging "svn-add" with "(svn|cvs)-add".

Comment: You're welcome ! And thanks to you for the question, I learnt something too. Apparently, you can also customize according to the options in the command-line replacing the * after `svn-add` with something like `option-depth-1`. I'm currently trying this feature.